# Create New Project with VS 2012 PRO on TFS Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm getting this Message when trying to create a new project:

[image]

TFS 2012 Express and Visual Studio 2012 is installed in a separate Machines. All machines are members of the Active Directory, behind proxy and comes with Kaspersky EndPoint 10 MR.

Also I'm a TFS Console Administrator and have the highest rights available.

> **Visual Studio 2012 Machine Setup:**
>
> - Professional Version with Update 4;
> - Windows 7 Pro SP1;
>
> **TFS Machine Setup:**
>
> - TFS 2013 Express (TFS 12.0.21005.1 Tfs2013.RTM);
> - Windows 7 Pro SP1

Comment: Found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b0ea4b4-c849-4c8b-a7e1-0ec0c7dd3eb4/unable-to-create-team-project-on-tfs-2013-preview-with-visual-studio-2012-update-3?forum=tfsgeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an updated version of Team Explorer (the connector between VS and TFS) since you are using TFS 2013 and VS 2012. VS 2012 ships with Team Explorer 2012 which can connect to TFS 2012 and earlier versions.

Take a look at the compatibility charts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx

Perhaps you need Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661

Comment: Thanks @madannes I found out there is version of TFS Express 2012 update 4; Replacing with TFS 2013 will solve my problem, will it?

Comment: If I understand your question, I don't think replacing TFS 2012 with TFS 2013 will solve the problem. The compatibility page shows VS 2012 coming standard with Team Explorer 2012 which can connect to TFS 2012 and older. But I believe your solution is to either use VS 2013 with TFS 2013, or get Team Explorer Everywhere that will allow VS 2012 to connect to TFS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the reason this throws the error message because the Team Explorer and TFS should be aligned with same version. In my context, I was using Team Explorer 2012 which ships with VS 2012 against a TFS Express 2013.

> Team Explorer Version and the TFS Version should be the same to avoid this error appearing.

There were few things you could do,

> As @madannes mentioned in his post above to use Team Explorer Everywhere

and

> As [Vivek Bansod explains in the MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4e8c7b3-fbcd-4ba2-a268-b4881a63e73e/unable-to-create-project-using-team-explorer-2012?forum=tfsgeneral), I used the [Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads) (The shell version of VS 2013), to create a Team Project and then continued to Add Solution, Check-In and Check-Out operation against TFS Express 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Download Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776)  and create a project there. These projects can be connected to from VS 2012.